# React Three Fiber / How Can access child position inside the useFrame Hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber

I made a simple Earth sphere rotating around 0 axis. Then I have added a child (the moon) but I can't figure if it is possible to also modify its position inside the useFrame hook of the Earth.

```js
    const Earth = (props) => {
    
        const ref = useRef()
        const texture = useLoader(THREE.TextureLoader, "/03earth.jpg")
        const coef = 0.1
        const delta = 6
        useFrame(state => {
            ref.current.rotation.y += 0.01
            ref.current.position.x = Math.cos(state.clock.elapsedTime * coef) * delta
            ref.current.position.z = Math.sin(state.clock.elapsedTime * coef) * delta
    
        })
    
        return (
            <mesh ref={ref} {...props} castShadow receiveShadow>
                <sphereGeometry />
                <meshPhysicalMaterial map={texture} />
                <Moon/> )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access sub components by specifying their index in children:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { Canvas, useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { OrbitControls } from "@react-three/drei";
import * as THREE from "three";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}>
      <Canvas>
        <OrbitControls />
        <Earth />
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
}

const Earth: React.FC = () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  useFrame((state) => {
    ref.current.rotation.y = state.clock.getElapsedTime();
    // Here 
    ref.current.children[0].position.y = Math.sin(state.clock.getElapsedTime());
  });
  return (
    <mesh ref={ref}>
      <sphereGeometry args={[1, 32, 32]} />
      <meshNormalMaterial />
      <mesh position={[1, 1, 1]}>
        <sphereGeometry args={[0.2, 32, 32]} />
        <meshNormalMaterial />
      </mesh>
    </mesh>
  );
};
```

sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-rgb-ry2f1h?file=/src/App.tsx